# Object Id of an object across the jvms?

Tags: java

I have a question on object ID of an object across JVMs. ie Say suppose i have persisted an object created on JVM1, and now I want to use the same object on JVM2.

1. So how to do that.
2. Will the object Id of the object same on both the JVM?
3. If yes for the above question, then what will be the case if the JVM2 has already an object with the objectID same as the one which is persisted.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object won't exist on JVM2 until you deserialize it. There's no concept of a "universal object ID" in Java - if you need an ID for your objects, you'll have to add it yourself. You could add a UUID field to your object; you'd then want to maintain some sort of cache to allow you to spot duplicates.

Are you really sure you need all of this? It may be worth taking another look at the bigger picture and redesigning.

Comment: Actually we have a multi node implementation. And in all the nodes an object should be with the same object ID. so this is the requirement.

Comment: Object ID sounds like something that is specific to your application then, is that correct?

Comment: @gurukulki: Does your object not already have its own form of identity though? If you've got some natural key, that should quite possibly be what you use elsewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Check out serialization [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) or alternatively you could use RMI [- check out this link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

I'm not really sure what you mean by Object Id, if you mean the reference you get printed out when you print out an object with no toString method then, this is not an object ID this is the memory address reference and will be different on each JVM and different on different invocations of the same program.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a UUID to your object to create an unique id.

- [UUID javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

  UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

Comment: (+1 for new stuff!) I've not seen that before, have you used it, if so, where?

Comment: @James B until now I didn't need this, I usually use a unique Id (from applications config) of a node or it's IP address.

Comment: I think it's handy, I've always used some combination of the current time in millis and some semi-unique string hash from the object, but this could save me doing something that always felt a bit cludgey - thanks!